# Get Page Filename from Core Service GetListXml

Tags: core-service

I would like to get the filename with a core service GetListXml call.  Currently my returned XML is:

```
<tcm:Item ID="tcm:9-26-64" Title="abc" Type="64" Modified="2013-03-27T21:27:54"
          IsNew="false" Icon="T64L0P0" 
          xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
</tcm:Item>
```

Can I use a different filter to get the filename?

```
var tridionItems = client.GetListXml(
    uri,
    new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
    {
        ItemTypes = new[] {
            Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ItemType.Component, 
            Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ItemType.Page },
            Recursive = recursive
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately this information is not available in the list XML. The best you can do is set `IncludeRelativeWebDavUrlColumn` to `true`. This will give you `URL` column like `URL="/webdav/Test/root/page.tpg"`. You can then split this value by `/` and pick the last member.

Alternatively, if you are on SDL Tridion 2013 you can use `GetList` method with `BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended`. This will give you `IdentifiableObject`s list which you can then cast to pages and get `FileName`

Comment: The WebDAVURL does not expose the file name of the page though, even though it resembles it superficially. Instead, it uses the title of the page. I think you have no alternative but to open the page itself.

Comment: Yes, I am opening the pages now.  It is an optional feature in the app, so won't slow it down all the time...